# Apollo Client 3 - how to properly implement optimistic response?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, response, apollo-client

I have some queries and mutations and one mutation updates quite big entity so I want to add `optimistic response` after mutate function is fired. The thing is that even if I pass to `optimisticResponse` object, full data that will be also returned when mutation completes the job it does not add it to cache - it seems that data is refreshed when mutation response is ready since having `optimistic response` or not the time of updating UI is the same so I assume `optimistic response` does not work.

Some code examples I have:

**Mutation:**

```
mutation UpdateList($id: ID, $data: ListData) {
  updateList(id: $id, data: $data) {
    list_id // 1
    name
  }
}
```

**action**

```
const [action] = useMutation(mutation_from_above)
// async body function so await can be used
await action({ variables: { id: 1, data: { name: 'secret name' }}, optimisticResponse: {
    updateList: {
      __typename: 'List',
      list_id: 1,
      name: 'some updated name until data is back'
    }
  })
```

and of course I have updated my id field for typename in the cache config like that:

```
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      List: {
        keyFields: ['list_id'],
      },
    },
  }),
```

and it looks pretty simple but for me it does not work. I also checked on API side and response from mutation is the same I pass to the `optimisticResponse` object. Is there some important point why it is not working ? Can someone explain me what to do in order to get this work ?

Thanks, cheers!

Comment: The graphQL-related code appears good, have you checked the UI and server to see if there is anything there causing the data to not update after the mutation completes?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding this might solve it like refreshing the cache might update the value and not persist

```
update: () => {
  user.refresh();
  // feel free to change the user to your stuff
},
```